# DocuSign - Password expiry on SOBO user

Tags: docusignapi

We are using the API with Send on Behalf functionality in our system would like to check on the impact of the expiry of the SOBO’s user password on the API.

1. What will happen during the API calls when the password for the SOBO user has expired.
2. Alternatively, can we exclude those accounts from the password expiration policy?
3. If not, how should we go about ensuring that the password expiry does not result in failure of the API calls.

Comment: Just wanted to confirm something - Lets say that account has user memberships of A,B,C. User F will be sending envelopes on behalf of users A,B,C. When making the SOBO API call, you will specify the password for user F. If user F's password expires, then your API call will definitely fail. I do not expect the API call to fail if users A,B,C have their passwords expire. I also know that on an account level setting you can specify 'non expiring passwords' but this applies to all users membership of that account. I will see if there is any way to have user level specific password expirations.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The security requirement for our system is such that the password policies has to expire within 90 days so I am unable to specify non expiring passwords. We can probably mitigate the expiry of the SOBO user's password by routinely changing the passwords before the expiry. For this: 'I do not expect the API call to fail if users A,B,C have their passwords expire.', is there any quick way where I can test this? Additionally, are there any practices regarding this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Password expiry is only enforced on logging into the WebApp. The general best practice is to have your API (or SOBO) user never use the DocuSign Web Application.

So, even if the account has a 30 day user password expiry it will not be enforced via the API and the password itself will only expire on a login attempt via https://account.docusign.com/#/web/login.